# PowerShell Unexpected Token Error

Tags: windows-10, powershell, pdf, xpdf

> ***Question:*** I am running the following script in Windows 10 via the PowerShell ISE

```
cd C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\pdfs
$FILES= ls *.pdf
foreach ($f in $FILES) {
  "C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.01.01\bin32\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 "$f"
}
```

> I am receiving the following errors
>
> - unexpected token 'enc' in expression or statement
> - unexpected token 'UTF-8' in expression or statement
>
> How do I correct those error ?

---

I suspect, although I am by no means certain, the error is due to incorrect " or ' marks. I have attempted the following change

```
cd C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\pdfs
$FILES= ls *.pdf
foreach ($f in $FILES) {
  "C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.01.01\bin32\pdftotext.exe -enc UTF-8 $f"
}
```

; which surprisingly executes but fails to generate any text files and I am expecting those files to be found in the folder ...\pdfs.

[Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/1417867/export-all-pdf-files-as-text-using-adobe-acrobar-pro-dc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Solution:** I was missing an ampersand, &. A deeper search on Stack Overflow turned up  this
>   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438231/get-parsererror-parentcontainserrorrecordexception-when-executing-pyt);
>   which provided me with the correction. Very fast, and much faster than anything native in Adobe Acrobat DC !

```
cd C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\pdfs
$FILES= ls *.pdf
foreach ($f in $FILES) {
  & "C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.01.01\bin32\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 "$f"
}
```